# How to nest the values of a first dictionary into the values of a second dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have two dictionaries. I would like to request your kind help to solve the following issue:

1. The first one has 339 keys-values pairs. The values may have a random lenght from cero to 10.
2. The secong one has 215 keys-values pairs. In the same case, the values have a random lenght.

The values of the first dictionary are one or more of the keys from the second. Sometinhg like that:

- dict1=[REQ-1:{value-1, value-2}, REQ-2:{}, REQ-3:{value-3, value-6, value-10},...]
- dict2=[value-1:{pcr-1,pcr-8}, value-2:{pcr-2,pcr-3,pcr-4},....]

How can I nest the values of the second into the values of the first one?:

```
dict3=[  
REQ-1:{value-1:{pcr-1,pcr-8},value-2:{pcr-2,pcr-3,pcr-4}},  
REQ-2:{},   
REQ-3:{value-3:{...},value-6:{...},value-10:{...}}
,...]
```

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Dictionaries in python are created using {}, not []. {} is also the operator for a set if you don't use key-value pairs. That aside, I'm assuming you meant to have "REQ-1" and so on be strings, as hyphens are not allowed in python variable names.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by iterating over the first dictionary. You can either do this using a for loop or with a dictionary generator.

Assuming every value in the first dictionary actually exists in the second:

```py
# For loop
dict3 = {} # Create an empty dictionary for us to populate
for key in dict1: # Iter over each of the keys in dict1
    subdict = {} # This will be the nested dictionary
    for item in dict1[key]: # Iter over each item in the list at that location in the dict
        subdict[item] = dict2[item] # Get the corresponding list from dict2 and store it in the nested dictionary
    dict3[key] = subdict # store the nested dictionary

# Dictionary generator
dict3 = {key: {item: dict2[item] for item in dict1[key]} for key in dict1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind contribution, it worked !

Comment: Please accept this as the answer if it worked for you.